# Change bootstrap columns' content flow from horizontal to vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, responsive-design, responsive

I've got a question about bootstrap columns. I'm making a file explorer, and I'd like it to resemble Windows file explorer.
Problem is, Windows is sorting files vertically, and my code is sorting them horizontally. So far I've got it like that:

A B C

D E F

And I'd like it to be like that:

A C E

B D F

My code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let entity of entities">
         //content here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing I need some smart usage of index in my for loop, however, I'm not fluent enough in Angular to do it cleanly and effitiently :/ Length of entities array is also often changing and can be empty or contain even over a houndred entities. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you have more like ABCDEFGHIJKLMN ?

Comment: I'd like them to be evenly distributed between columns but sorted vertically. As you can see I've got up to 4 columns, so in your example first column would be A B C D, second E F G H, third I J K L and the last column M and N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of solving this, is using CSS columns:

```css
    @media (min-height: 576px) {
        .cols {
            columns: 2 200px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-height: 768px) {
        .cols {
            columns: 3 200px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-height: 992px) {
        .cols {
            columns: 4 200px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cols">
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
        <div>E</div>
        <div>F</div>
        <div>G</div>
        <div>H</div>
        <div>I</div>
        <div>J</div>
        <div>K</div>
        <div>L</div>
        <div>M</div>
        <div>N</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More info on CSS colums is available at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

The availability on various browsers can be checked here:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn